Using nchar in Hebrew to count characters
nchar(x) in base R counts the number of characters in a character vector.
Hebrew includes consonants and vowels, with the vowels below the consonants.  Should the following give 13 or 8?  Is there a way to force the answer to 8?  Thank you.
nchar("מָתֵימָטִיקָה")
[1] 13
I expected the answer to be 8.
